# Get number of characters in label contents in Blazor

Tags: c#, label, blazor

How can I get the length or number of characters in label content using blazor and .net 5.0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G25Vp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G25Vp.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you mean as far as i see:

```
<Label>@Label1Text</Label>
<Label>@Label1Text.Length.ToString()</Label>

@code
{
    public string Label1Text{ get; set; } = "RandomText";}
}
```

Comment: Hello Senna,
I tried to use Bind in label but it doesn't work for me !

Comment: Could you show what you tried.

Comment: I added another response to show you what I want exactly

Comment: I changed my answer. I'm sorry it couldn't be clearer. I don't have Visual Studio installed so I had to use the Web Blazor application which isn't great.

Comment: I just need to put the length of string of first label  in the second label.

Comment: Made it even more clear.

Comment: I added another answer

Answer (score -1):

I just need to return the length of a label which is in this case for example : 29 character
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOYEC.png)

Comment: If you want to add something to your answer, edit it or write it as a comment.